# configure catch-all alias in postfix using mysql

Tags: postfix-mta

It seems like my catch-all alias doesn't work.
When I use

```
postmap -q test@example.org mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
```

There is no output.
But when I command

```
 postmap -q jack@example.org mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
```

the output is

```
 john@example.org.
```

How can I fix this?

The configure query is:

```
query= SELECT destination FROM virtual_aliases WHERE source='%s'
```

Table virtual_aliases:

```
id  domain_id   source             destination
5   1           @example.org        john@example.org
7   1           john@example.org    john@example.org
8   1           jack@example.org    john@example.org
```

Table virtual_domains:

```
id  name
1   example.org
```

Table virtual_users:

```
id  domain_id   password    email
1   1           pwd         john@example.org
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `mysql` query should be

```
SELECT destination FROM virtual_aliases WHERE source='%s' 
UNION ALL  
SELECT destination FROM virtual_aliases WHERE source='@%d' 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT destination FROM virtual_aliases WHERE source='%s')
```

Comment: Thank this statement worked. Its important to write this statement in one line.

Comment: Ya I wrote it in separate lines for clarity

Answer (score 0):

@clement is correct but there is a simpler query that would work that is easier on the sql server.  Here is what worked for me:

Changed query line in
/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf

```
query = select distinct destination from virtual_aliases where source='%s' or source = '@%d';
```

Comment: Note that this version will not work if you want some specific address mappings with the catchall as a fallback. (the `and not exists` part of clement's answer). Also from a database dev's PoV using `where ... or ...` like this isn't great as it will likely result in a table scan instead of two index seeks, though that is unlikely to be significant unless you manage a great many mail accounts on the same system.